# Query not working when trying to get last 3 years data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a separate column for a year and month in my database table called Logs and I want to retrieve logs between 2 dates like below:

So if I say retrieve logs between `01/01/2018` to last month that is `02/01/2021` then it should retrieve all the logs but I am not getting any result with the query below:

```
select COUNT(*)
from Logs
where ((LogYear >= YEAR('01/01/2018') and LogMonth >=Month('01/01/2018')) and (LogYear <=YEAR('02/01/2021') and LogMonth < =Month('02/01/2021')))
```

**Output: 0 records**

When I run this query, I am getting a 0 count although I have data for all the year.

What's the issue with this query?

Sample Data:

```
LogID   LogYear     LogMonth
1       2018           1
2       2018           2
3       2018           3
4       2018           4
```

I am trying to retrieve data from `1-Jan-2018 to 1-February-2021`.

Comment: @DaleK I have added sample data to my question. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @DaleK Sure. I will create a plunker. Give me some time.

Comment: As it currently stands, your query will only consider rows where month is either 1 or 2 due to the way your query is written. You want ALL rows for years between 2018 and 2020 and only  the first 2 months of 2021. Do you SEE why your query doesn't work now?

Comment: @DaleK Updated the question to reflect that

Comment: @SMor Yes, I see that. Thanks for pointing that out. Could you please tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare a date by comparing its component parts, you have to build a proper date and then compare them. Unfortunately this is unsargable i.e. unable to use indexes, you would be better of storing actual dates rather than date components.

As an aside, to avoid unexpected behaviour always use an unambiguous date format.

As you mention you are passing the values from C# just ensure you set the SqlParameter type to `date` not `datetime` to avoid any possible issues with time components.

```
declare @Logs table (LogId int, LogYear int, LogMonth int);

declare @StartDate date = '01 Jan 2018', @EndDate date = '01 Feb 2021';

insert into @Logs (LogID, LogYear, LogMonth)
values
(1, 2018, 1),
(2, 2018, 2),
(3, 2018, 3),
(4, 2018, 4),
(5, 2021, 2),
(6, 2021, 3);

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM @Logs
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS(LogYear, LogMonth, 1) >= @StartDate
AND DATEFROMPARTS(LogYear, LogMonth, 1) <= @EndDate;
```

Sample data (tweaked to check end case) produces a result of 5 because record id 5 is in the window and id 6 isn't.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping and also for additional info for my knowledge. I want data till 01 Feb 2021

Comment: Sorry but let's say if my FromDate and ToDate is like "01/01/2021 12:00:00 AM" and "02/01/2021 12:00:00 AM", then will there be any issue since you are constructing the whole date and then comparing?

Comment: You can't have a from date or to date which include a time component - thats a datetime - and you aren't storing a day, let alone a time, so you have to stick to a date compare.

Comment: Actually I am passing the FromDate and ToDate as a variable from C# application and there I have a DateTime variable which is including 12:00 AM in date that's why

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow then you need to ensure your question accurately reflects your situation - otherwise you won't get the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah sorry but I didn't knew that we can solve this by only constructing the date. I thought I had the logic problem in my solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the date in an ordered form first, either through converting into a `DATETIME` or an `INT`.

Here an example with `INT`:

```
WITH Logs2 (ID, LogDate) AS (
    SELECT ID, ((LogYear * 10000) + (LogMonth * 100) + LogDay)
    FROM Logs
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Logs2
WHERE (LogDate >= 20180101) AND (LogDate < 20210201)
```

But of course better would be to convert the 3 columns into a `DATETIME`, `DATETIME2` or `DATETIMEOFFSET`.

Comment: Why use a datetime when OP wants a date? And there is no `LogDay` column.

Comment: Don't know, never ever considered it (I always work with point-in-times). By the way, your solution with `DATEFROMPARTS` is the better I think, mine was more of a hack...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DateFrom   datetime    =   '01/01/2018'
    ,   @DateTo     datetime    =   '02/01/2021'
    
SELECT 
        COUNT(*)
FROM    Logs
WHERE           LTRIM(LogYear*100 + LogMonth)
        BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar(6), @DateFrom   , 112) 
            AND CONVERT(varchar(6), @DateTo     , 112)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select COUNT(*)
from Logs
where (LogYear between 2018 and 2020)
or (logyear=2021 and logMonth <= 2)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for the general case of setting a date range though.

Comment: I agree but the query is less expensive and fits the data model provided.